# Why $(+k| 1\leqslant k \leqslant n : 1/2^{k}) = 1-1/2^{n}$?

Tags: algorithms

I'm analyzing this problem I've found on a lecture notes:

$f_{1}= (+k| 1\leqslant k \leqslant n : 1/2^{k})$

The purpose is to compute a simpler version of this expression:
{
$f_{1}(n+1)=f_{1}.n+1/2^{n+1}$

$=$

$f_{1}(n+1)-f_{1}.n=1/2^{n+1}$

$=$

$(E-1)f_{1}=\left \langle (1/2)(1/2)^{n} \right \rangle$

$\Rightarrow$

$(E-1)(E-1/2)f_{1}=0$

[**Note:** In this context, $E$ is the displacement operator, *.i.e.*,, $E^{k}(a_{n})=a_{n+k}$.]

**What I need to know is how do the last expression is gotten?**

The computation -expression simplification- continues as follows:

With constants $A$ and $B$:

$f_{1}.n=A+B/2^{n}$

$=$

$f_{1}.n=1-1/2^{n}$

Comment: What does $(+k\mid\cdots)$ mean?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD It looks like a strange attempt to adapt the fold operation of functional programming languages into non-programming environment.  It's like set comprehension, then $+$ (sum) over the set.  There is a notation very similar to this that Dijsktra and Knuth used that is very useful, but with angle brackets and the operation $+$ is distinguished better.

Answer (score 1):

If
$f(n)
= (+k| 1\leqslant k \leqslant n : 1/2^{k})
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
f(n+1)-f(n)
&=(+k| 1\leqslant k \leqslant n+1 : 1/2^{k})-(+k| 1\leqslant k \leqslant n : 1/2^{k})\\
&=(+k| n+1\leqslant k \leqslant n+1 : 1/2^{k})\\
&=1/2^{n+1}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if
$f(n)
=1-1/2^{n}
$,
then
$f(n+1)
=f(n)+1/2^{n+1}
=1-1/2^{n}+1/2^{n+1}
=1-1/2^{n+1}
$.

Comment: How did you got $f(n)=1-1/2^{n}$?

Comment: Look at values for small n, make a guess, try to prove it.